# Pie chart changes depending on dict key size

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am plotting 4 pie charts in one figure using a function. However, I realized that depending on how long the key names are in the dict, the pie charts move. How can I fix this and keep them looking like figure 1?

Here is my function:

```
def create_pie_chart(title, pie_dict, top_design, pyplot, nbr, cord1, cord2, loc_nbr):
  #pyplot.figure()
  counts = collections.Counter(pie_dict)  # color for pie chart
  pyplot.subplot(2, 2, nbr)
  pyplot.pie([float(v) for v in counts.values()], labels=[k for k in counts],
            autopct='%1.1f%%', radius=9, shadow=True, labeldistance=1.05, startangle=125,
             pctdistance=0.7, center=(cord1, cord2))
  centre_circle = pyplot.Circle((0,0), 2, fc='white')
  pyplot.gca().set_title(title+top_design)
  fig = pyplot.gcf()
  fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
  #pyplot.suptitle(title+top_design)
  pyplot.axis('equal')
  pyplot.legend(labels=counts, loc='center right', fontsize = 'x-small', bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, 0.2, 1, 1), facecolor='grey')
  pyplot.tight_layout()
  pyplot.title(title+top_design, fontsize = 'medium')
```

I call it this way:

```
create_pie_chart("second pie chart\n ", dict_2, "two", pyplot, 2, 0, 0, 1)
```

I want it to look like this: 
[image]

However, when the dict key sizes become bigger, they look like this:
[image].

Comment: `tight_layout` will adjust the spacings, such that everything fits well into the figure. You can remove `tight_layout` and adjust the parameters manually via `plt.subplots_adjust`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Is it possible to change the subplot params per different subplot (change the parameters per quadrant instead of the whole figure). If so, how?

Comment: No that's not possible, but for a 2x2 it's also not necessary, since you have 3 margins per direction to control and for that your have 3 parameters; 6 in total.